# Cleaning up a 7x7 matrix

Tags: matrices, siunitx

I am looking to see if someone can help make this jacobian matrix look a little cleaner. I have given the code and a screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{document}


\[ J\Big|_{(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.1000363    & 0.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0.10     & -0.450035 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0      & 0 & -0.140385 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0      & 0 & 0.14  & -3.5 \cdot 10^{-5} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & -0.09 & 0.54 & 0.54 \\ 
    0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & -0.23 & 0 \\ 
  0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0.14 & -0.09
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: thank you, would you be able to help me out?

Comment: Looks fine to me (apart from overfull hbox).  Maybe remove the subscript from `J` to make it fit.

Comment: @fr14 - Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't been particularly specific as to what "a little cleaner" means to you. Hopefully, the following solution meets your objectives. Note that the only required package is `siunitx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-digits=false,tight-spacing]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[ 
J\Bigr|_{\mathbf{0}_{(7\times1)}} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}
     *{3}{S[table-format=-1.6]}
     c 
     *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2]} @{}}
-0.1000363  & 0.45 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0.10   & -0.450035 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0      & 0 & -0.140385 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0      & 0 & 0.14  & \num{-3.5e-5} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & -0.09 & 0.54 & 0.54 \\ 
0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & -0.23 & 0 \\ 
0      & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0.14 & -0.09
\end{array}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```